# What alternative ways are there to specify binomial successes/trials in a formula?

Tags: r, formula

Suppose you are modelling binomial data where each response is a number of successes (y) from a number of trials (N) with some explanatory variables (a and b). There's a few functions that do this kind of thing, and they all seem to use different methods to specify y and N.

In glm, you do `glm(cbind(y,N-y)~a+b, data = d)`  (matrix of success/fail on LHS)

In inla, you do `inla(y~a+b, Ntrials=d$N, data=d)` (specify number of trials separately)

In glmmBUGS, you do `glmmBUGS(y+N~a+b,data=d)` (specify success + trials as terms on LHS)

When programming new methods, I've always thought it best to follow what glm does, since that's where people would normally first encounter binomial response data. However, I can never remember if its `cbind(y,N-y)` or `cbind(y,N)` - and I usually seem to have success/number of trials in my data rather than success/number of fails - YMMV.

Other approaches are possible of course. For example using a function on the RHS to mark whether the variable is number of trials or number of fails:

```
myblm( y ~ a + b + Ntrials(N), data=d)
myblm( y ~ a + b + Nfails(M), data=d)  # if your dataset has succ/fail variables
```

or defining an operator to just do a cbind, so you can do:

```
myblm( y %of% N ~ a + b, data=d)
```

thus attaching some meaning to the LHS making it explicit.

Has anyone got any better ideas? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I like `%of%` because it makes the order obvious.  But it's less standard....

Comment: `glm` also allows the proportion to be specified on the LHS with an additional `weights` argument giving the denominators

Answer (score 1):

You can also let `y` be fraction in which case you need to supply the `weights`. It is not in the `formula` argument but an almost equal amount of keystrokes as if it was in the `formula`. Here is an example

```r
> set.seed(73574836)
> x <- runif(10)
> n <- sample.int(10, 2)
> y <- sapply(mapply(rbinom, size = 1, n, (1 + exp(1 - x))^-1), function(x) 
+   sum(x == 1))
> df <- data.frame(y = y, frac = y / n, x = x, weights = n)
> df
   y  frac      x weights
1  2 1.000 0.9051       2
2  5 0.625 0.3999       8
3  1 0.500 0.4649       2
4  4 0.500 0.5558       8
5  0 0.000 0.8932       2
6  3 0.375 0.1825       8
7  1 0.500 0.1879       2
8  4 0.500 0.5041       8
9  0 0.000 0.5070       2
10 3 0.375 0.3379       8
> 
> # the following two fits are identical
> summary(glm(cbind(y, weights - y) ~ x, binomial(), df))

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(y, weights - y) ~ x, family = binomial(), 
    data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.731  -0.374   0.114   0.204   1.596  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -0.416      0.722   -0.58     0.56
x              0.588      1.522    0.39     0.70

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 9.5135  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 9.3639  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 28.93

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

> summary(glm(frac ~ x, binomial(), df, weights = weights))

Call:
glm(formula = frac ~ x, family = binomial(), data = df, weights = weights)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.731  -0.374   0.114   0.204   1.596  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -0.416      0.722   -0.58     0.56
x              0.588      1.522    0.39     0.70

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 9.5135  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 9.3639  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 28.93

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

The reason the above works comes down to what `glm` actually does for binomial outcomes. It computes a fraction for each observation and a weight associated with the observation regardless of how you specify the outcome. Here is a snippet from `?glm` which gives a hint of what is going in the estimation

> If a `binomial` `glm` model was specified by giving a two-column response,
>   the weights returned by `prior.weights` are the total numbers of cases
>   (factored by the supplied case weights) and the component `y` of the
>   result is the proportion of successes.

Alternatively, you can make a wrapper for `glm.fit` or `glm` using `model.frame`. See the `...` argument in `?model.frame`

> `...` for `model.frame` methods, a mix of further arguments such as
>   data, `na.action`, `subset` to pass to the default method. Any
>   additional arguments (such as `offset` and `weights` or other named
>   arguments) which reach the default method are used to create further
>   columns in the model frame, with parenthesised names such as
>   `"(offset)"`.

## Comment

I saw Ben Bolker's comment afterwards. The above is what he points out.

Answer (score 0):

I like this method from the glm documentation:

> For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be
>   specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all
>   others success)

This comports well with the way successes and failures often arise in my experience.  One is a catch-all (e.g. "didn't vote") and there are a variety of ways to achieve the other (e.g. "voted for A", "voted for B").  I hope it's clear from the way I'm phrasing this that "success" and "failure" as defined by `glm` can be defined arbitrarily so that the first level corresponds to a "failure" and all the other levels are a "success".

Answer (score -2):

From r's help page on glm :
"...or as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of **successes** and **failures**"

So it has to be cbind(Y, N-Y)

Comment: what does this add to the OP's question?  He already stated this, I think.

Comment: I guess it has to do with the following comment by the OP: _I can never remember if its `cbind(y,N-y)` or `cbind(y,N)` ..._. It is not an answer to the OP's question though.